# How to normalize a json file in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

I want to normalize a json file that looks like:

```
[{ "ID":1, "Rev":2, "Fields":{"System.Id":1, "System.State":"CLosed", "System.Title":"ABC", "Value":"Functional"}, "Comments":[] }]
```

I tried to use the json_normalize function in the following way:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'Fields', ['Id', 'Rev', 'Comments'], record_prefix = "Fields_")
```

But the above code creates several rows pertaining to the same ID number. I want the code to create new columns that are described by "Fields" at the same level as the other columns in the json file. Each row should have one ID number and the other details for that ID number. How can I implement this?

Edit: I need the output to look like this:

Required Output:

[image: Required Ouptut]

Instead, what I get is this:

[image: Output I got]

Comment: Can you please share how your expected output will look like?

Comment: Hi,

I need the output to have one row per ID number like this:

>ID REV   System.ID System.State System.Title Value     Comments
>1 2   1                 Closed         ABC                 Functional

Comment: Edited the original question, please check.

Comment: Okay, I've just posted an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.json_normalize()` will return row having one id along with the other details and then you can `replace` `"Fields."` with `""` in all columns

```
data= [{ "ID":1, "Rev":2, "Fields":{"System.Id":1, "System.State":"CLosed", "System.Title":"ABC", "Value":"Functional"}, "Comments":[] }]
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df.columns = [c.replace("Fields.", "") for c in df.columns]
```

**Output**

[image]